# Tracing SSH/login process and properly isolating filesystem from unauthorized access

Tags: linux, permissions, chroot, synology

For some context, I am dealing with a Synology RackStation unit running a near-fully updated version of DSM. The specifics of that are nice to know if you're familiar with Synology but not necessary, because it's just a customized Linux distro.

First of all, they somehow locked down SSH so that only people part of the 'administrators' group can use it. I'm not sure exactly how - I suspected PAM, but when I disabled it and tried to use a `Match` clause in `sshd_config`, that didn't change the behaviour. When I run `ssh` with `-vvv` flags it does seem like authentication succeeds, then the connection terminates *afterwards*.

So, my first question is how to trace where and why the connection terminates.

Unrelated to that, we had an issue syncing up with Amazon S3 and needed to get Synology involved for troubleshooting and debugging. In order to get their support, they often ask for remote access. In this case, I can't give it to them because of security implications. So I thought I could set up a chroot environment with bind-mounts to everything except the data that needs to be protected.

In fact, that worked very well in testing, but obviously in order for SSH to work, again, the Synology remote-access account had to be part of the `administrators` group, and if that were the case, they'd have complete access to the UI where they could ostensibly give themselves access to files on the device through a WebUI app.

So this creates a problem for me. I trust Synology and its employees but the agreements in place don't care about trust, relationships and reputation. They just say, nobody unauthorized can have access to the data, period.

How would you solve the problem of a remote user needing fairly open access to a device you own without giving them full access to your data, and without giving them even access to change their own permissions?

Comment: Hi @MarkPlotnick, what we're experiencing is apparently a bug, so it's likely restricted to the unit being used in production and might not show up on a demo unit they send us.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about protecting data at rest, you should already have considered what would happen if someone stole your NAS. The only way to secure your data is to encrypt it on the disk. Synology provide a [guide](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_shared_folders_on_my_Synology_NAS) for this.

In your case, you can select "manually decrypt" and hold the key file on a separate computer, and so choose at each boot whether to decrypt or not.  As I understand it, Synology uses `ecryptfs` as the mechanism, so alternatively you can probably find how "automatically decrypt" keeps the key file, and then manually remove it temporarily when allowing remote debug access.

Comment: I did consider this. The fact that the key file has to be manually selected on boot is prohibitive. Instead we bolstered physical security to make it very difficult to get to the device to steal. I recognize your point though and it is a really good one.